Can i reverse javascript framework build bundles into human reading code?
I converted my reactjs project into build using npm run build  file and when i opened the code it is barely readable
it is so scrambled that i can't even understand what the code does, so is there any way of reverting build files into more readable code like converting exe files into human readable code using reverse engineering softwares, is there any way to achieve that?

Why do you need this?  Why not just refer back to the original code used to create the production build?

i know i can do that but i want to reverse engineer a reactjs bundle just as normal applications for different purpose for like ethical hacking.

Unless it has sourcemaps that are available to you, the best you can do is prettify it and then figure it out through raw engineering skill and the debugger. This is the same if you reverse engineered an .exe. There's no magic way to get to the original source with the original function/variable names there, either.  A highly skilled engineer has to figure out what routines do what.

Unless it has sourcemaps that are available to you, the best you can do is prettify it and then figure it out through raw engineering skill and the debugger. This is the same if you reverse engineered an .exe. There's no magic way to get to the original source with the original function/variable names there, either. A highly skilled engineer has to figure out what routines do what. –
adsy
Commentedyesterday
